# How to secure metamask to avoid theft

Tags: contract-development, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security, ethereumjs

I have a website with NODEJS and it's a Dapp.

There is some button to click and open MetaMask for signing a transaction.

I think an attacker car replace my ABI+Contract address and inject them with his contract and ABI. So if he take advantage of it, he can redirect ETH fund to his own benefit.

Is there any security to avoid this ?

Comment: Hi there. At what point do you think the attacker would inject his own code?

Comment: Expanding on @RichardHorrocks's comment, could you supply the code you're using to do this, and how you think an attacker could hijack it?